# Get tablespace of a given table in DB2

Tags: db2, table, tablespaces

What is the command to get the name of tablespace of a given table in DB2 database ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Db2 for LUW you can use this query. You get one row per table data partition (1 row for a non range partitioned table).

```
SELECT 
    SD.TBSPACE AS DATA_SPACE
,   SL.TBSPACE AS LONG_SPACE
,   SI.TBSPACE AS INDEX_SPACE
FROM 
          SYSCAT.DATAPARTITIONS P
JOIN      SYSCAT.TABLESPACES   SD ON SD.TBSPACEID = P.TBSPACEID
LEFT JOIN SYSCAT.TABLESPACES   SL ON SL.TBSPACEID = P.LONG_TBSPACEID
LEFT JOIN SYSCAT.TABLESPACES   SI ON SI.TBSPACEID = P.INDEX_TBSPACEID
WHERE
    TABSCHEMA = 'YOUR_SCHEMA' 
AND TABNAME   = 'YOUR_TABLE'
```

Comment: thanks for reply, let me try this command .